# JQuery :visible is not visible to every element except from head?

Tags: jquery, visible

I attended a test and this assertion was given as false:
$(':visible') have access to all visible elements in a document, except the elements from head tag as style, meta, scripts, title etc

Where is the error? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quick reading of [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

(...)

> All option elements are considered hidden, regardless of their
>   selected state.

So these are two quick answers why the statement isn't true (it has no access to elements with width/height equal zero and to all option elements).

I assume it's not the only reason, but this would be my first guess.